# Expected value random Fibonacci sequence

Tags: probability

For a random Fibonacci sequence given by $x_{n}=\pm x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}$ , why do we have that $E(x_n)=x_0$? I only see that $E(x_n)=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n-1}+x_{n-2})+\frac{1}{2}(-x_{n-1}+x_{n-2})=x_{n-2}$

Comment: $x_{n-2}$ is also a random variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting that all the $x_i$ are random variables themselves (for $i>1)$. Having considered this, you should reach the following result.$$E[x_n]=\frac12 (E[x_{n-1}]+ E[x_{n-2}])+\frac12 (-E[x_{n-1}]+ E[x_{n-2}])=E[x_{n-2}]=\cdots=\begin{cases}x_1&n\text{ odd}\\x_0&n\text{ even}\end{cases}$$

---

You may be more convinced by seeing an example. Suppose $x_0=1,x_1=2$. Then $$P(x_2=3)=P(x_2=-1)=\frac12$$ Then $E[x_2]=1=x_0$.$$P(x_3=5)=P(x_3=-1)=P(x_3=1)=P(x_3=3)=\frac14$$Then $E[x_3]=\frac{5-1+1+3}4=\frac84=2=x_1$

Finally, $$P(x_4=8)=\frac12P(x_4=-2)=\frac12P(x_4=2)=P(x_4=4)=P(x_4=0)=P(x_4=-4)=\frac18$$ Therefore $$E[x_4]=\frac{8-2-2+2+2+4+0-4}8=1=x_0$$

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, yes I concluded the same but I'm reading this paper where they say that $E(x_n)=x_0$ https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X06000229. And it's at the very beginning of the paper, they don't say anything about $n$ or $x_0$ or $x_1$ but now I know that what I thought was right, thank you!

Comment: @user2795243 it may be possible that the author simply assumes $x_0=x_1$, like in the Fibonacci sequence $1,1,2,3,5,8,13...$. But I do agree, there is confusion there. Glad to help!